# How to make RStudio Server persist after dev server signs out in Terminal?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have RStudio server set up on my dev server and can access it in my browser. However, Rstudio becomes unresponsive (`Error: Unable to establish connection with R session`) when my dev server signs out in Terminal, which happens automatically every few minutes. Once I sign back into the dev server in Terminal I can pick up where I left off. Is there a simple way to make Rstudio persist independently of the dev server signin?

Answer (score 1):

Yes!  You can use [screen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) or [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux) to disassociate safely from the terminal window without interrupting the program running inside the terminal.